# Error: index.js [BABEL] Cannot find module '@babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor'

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I created a react-native project by `npx react-native init project-name` command.

All the environment setup was done as per the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup).

Android Emulator was running and I started the server by running `yarn run android` command.
But I got this error. I haven't changed anything in the config and or other files.
Checked the node_moduels folder, this particular module is already there.
I am Using Windows 10.

Error message:

```
error: index.js: [BABEL] D:\firstapp\index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/helper-builder-binary-assignment-operator-visitor'
Require stack:
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator\lib\index.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\metro-react-native-babel-preset\src\configs\main.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\metro-react-native-babel-preset\src\index.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\module-types.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\configuration.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\files\index.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\index.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Worker.js
- D:\firstapp\node_modules\metro\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js (While processing: "D:\\firstapp\\node_modules\\metro-react-native-babel-preset\\src\\index.js")
```

[Error image from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93p1V.png).

Comment: Do you remember how/if you fixed this?